# How can send image from restFull web service?

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a simple restfull web service with c# using webApi.

Now, I want return besides normal information as

Number | String

also one or more images.

This is my web service:

```
[Route("getListUserCharacters")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage getListUserCharacters(UserDTO u)
        {

            try
            {

                //costruisco una lista fittizia di Esercizi da restituire
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new RMessage((short)status_code.Success, "Ok", getTestDementiaByPatient().ToArray()));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(string.Format("{0} {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new RMessage((short)status_code.Exception, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError.ToString()));
            }
        }
```

The method getTestDementia return a list of this object:

```
[DataContract]
    public class AvatarDTO
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "description")]
        public string description { get; set; }


        public class AvatarImage
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "idStatus")]
            public int idStatus { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "image")]
            public string image { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to send an image in field image. How can I do this ?

Comment: Use byte[] instead of string. Then `image = File.ReadAllBytes("pathToYourImageFile");`

Comment: Question is incomplete, what really happens when you try to send in current format, are you not able to get the image via de-serialization. Mostly images / videos are send as `byte[ ]`, use a serializer like protobuf to do the needful

Comment: What does `UserDTO` contains and how is the input used to `AvatarDTO`, which contains the image